Finding the length and area of certain regions of square and quarter circle
I have this geometric math question in mind.
Here's an image of a square and quarter circle
My goal is to determine the area of the highlighted area and length of $x_1$ and $x_2$.
I was able to determine $x_1$ to be $(\sqrt{2}-1)*R$ (Correct me if I'm wrong), but couldn't figure out the length of $x_2$ and the highlighted area.
Any help to solve this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Let $P=(x_P,y_P)$ be the intersection of the circle and the line $y=x-\frac{R}{2}$ in the first quadrant, i.e. the starting point of where we measure $x_2.$ You have to solve
$$ x_P^2+y_P^2 = R^2 \\
y_P = x_P-\frac{R}{2}
$$
which means
$$
x_P=\frac{(1+\sqrt{7})R}{4} \\
y_P=\frac{(-1+\sqrt{7})R}{4}
$$
and
$$
x_2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}(3-\sqrt{7})R}{4}
$$
Let $Q=(x_Q,y_Q)$ be the intersection between the circle and the line $y=x$ in the first quadrant, that is, $Q=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}R}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}R}{2}\right)$.
With a little bit of hand-waving regarding the notation, we obviously have
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \mathrm{highlighted\ area} \\
& =& \;\;\;\; \mathrm{area\ of\ trapezoid}\left(
\left(0,0\right),
\left(\frac{R}{2},0\right),
\left(R,\frac{R}{2}\right),
\left(R,R\right),
\right) \\
& & - \; \mathrm{area\ of\ circular\ sector}\left(Q, O ,P\right) \\
& & - \; \mathrm{area\ of\ triangle}\left(\left(0,0\right),
\left(\frac{R}{2},0\right),P \right)
\end{eqnarray}
The cosine of the angle $\alpha$ at the center of the circular sector is
$$\cos\alpha = \frac{x_Px_Q+y_Py_Q}{R^2} 
= \frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{7}}{4}= \frac{\sqrt{14}}{4}
$$
The area of the trapezoid is trivially $\frac{3}{8}R^2$.
The area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{R}{2}\cdot y_P = \frac{Ry_P}{4}$
Put all this together to get
$$
A = \left( \frac{3}{8} - \frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{14}}{4} - \frac{y_P}{4R}\right)R^2
$$

Awesome! Pretty much what I was looking for. That took me a while to confirm the proof.
